# PHP eliminar texto con expresión regular

Tags: php, text, str-replace

Muy buenas quisiera eliminar un texto con una expresión regular
el texto a eliminar va entre corchetes
y el codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
$string=  "texto1 y [texto2] todos los [otro texto]     textos que van entre corchetes [a] y no entre";
$patron= "/\[.*?\]/";
$cadena = str_replace($patron, '', $string);
```

pero no me funciona, me podría alguien ayudar?
gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str_replace` no funciona con expresiones regulares, lo que tienes que usar es [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$string=  "texto1 y [texto2] todos los [otro texto]     textos que van entre corchetes [a] y no entre";
$patron= "/\[.*?\]/";
$cadena = preg_replace($patron, '', $string);
```

Comment: Añadir tambien que si quiere sustituir todas las ocurrencias, necesitará añadir `/g` al final del patrón...